# Swift interface for ObjC functions in static library for swift code in iOS-7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a static library, lets call it S - which is written in Objective-C. Now few people who support iOS-7 have started using Swift, as a result of which I have to give the interface to my functions also in Swift.

I know that we can use bridging headers to directly import Objective-C code into Swift (within same project), but how should I do it for my static library?

Also, I cannot have Swift files in my static library - as Swift is only supported by dynamic frameworks. So, if I make dynamic frameworks, I cannot then deploy this library for iOS-7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. We need to make `module.modulemap` in the SDK (static library) and then the path to this module.modulemap needs to be added to `Import Paths in Swift Compiler - Search Paths in Build Settings`. Also, if the static library is being distributed via CocoaPods, podspec can be altered to do this setting automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The static library will become an integral part of the binary generated by the project linking to it. Therefore, including the headers of the static library in the bridging header should make its' functionality available from Swift code in that same project.

Comment: This works, but has an additional step on user's end to create bridge header and add the public header to this bridge file. Anyways to skip this part?

Comment: @prabodhprakash No, without exposing the Objective-C interfaces via the bridging header, Swift code won't be able to use it.

Comment: And this bridging header - can we somehow supply it in the static library? That can be directly consumed by the project adding the library?

Comment: The bridging header needs to be configured in the project settings and the library user might want to expose more Objective-C interfaces to their Swift code. So I would think that providing a single public header is the best you can do.